# Laravel queue stops working when server restart (plesk)

Tags: cron, queue, laravel-7, plesk, laravel-queue

I am using plesk for my server management. Yesterday server restarted automatically due to some updated . When my server turned on , it stops to process laravel queues . I run this command on my Laravel-project-root-directory to restart queues manually.
command : `nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon &`
Can i found a way to automatically run this command on my server on server restart. I am new to plesk & laravel queues.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't run supervisor, you could also use sansdaemon as a solution (https://github.com/orobogenius/sansdaemon).

once you've installed that, you can add a statement to the console/Kernel.php file:

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --sansdaemon')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
```

all should be working then the moment cron picks up again.

Comment: hi Erik, will it work automatically when server restarts? or i should manually run this on every server restart?

Comment: it should start by itself again if you've set cron to run the scheduler